# How is the Dominican ID verification digit determined?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I have been exploring how the "Check Digit" that is added to the end of the cédula is calculated. I understand that this "Verifying Digit" consists of the last two digits of the cedula plus an additional digit that is somehow calculated from the first nine digits of the cedula.

Example:

ID: 001-0052268-9 Verifier code: 895.

I have tried Luhn's algorithm, commonly used for ID number and credit card verification, but it seems that this algorithm does not apply to calculate the last digit of the "Verifying Digit" in the case of the Dominican cedula.

Therefore, I would like to kindly request any information you can provide on the algorithm or formula that is used to calculate this last digit of the "Verifying Digit".

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cédula_de_Identidad_y_Electoral#Technical_details) it should be a Luhn checksum: "The cédula number is broken up into three pieces: a series number (3 digits), a document number (7 digits), and a Luhn checksum."

Answer (score 0):

This works for the given ID:
$$
1\cdot0 + 2\cdot0 + 1\cdot1 + 2\cdot0 + 1\cdot0 + 2\cdot5 + 1\cdot2 + 2\cdot2 + 1\cdot6 + 2\cdot8 \\
= 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + (1+0) + 2 + 4 + 6 + (1+6) \\
= 21
$$
So the check digit should be $9$ since $21+9 \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$.

Comment: That's right but I'm looking for the last number of 895. In this particular case, how did I get to the digit 5?

Comment: @InveniumBusiness. It wasn't clear that "Verifying Digit" referred to "Verifier code".